# How to use "addTouchEventListener(<#const ccWidgetTouchCallback &callback#>)" in cocos2d-x v 3.10

Tags: cocos2d-x

Version:cocos2d-x v3.10
code:

```
Widget *xiaoruoBtn = (Widget*)rootNode->getChildByName("xiaoruoBtn");    
xiaoruo->addTouchEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::onClickCallBack, this));

void HelloWorld::onClickCallBack(Ref* pSender, TouchEventType type){
    switch (type) {
        ...
    }
}
```

question:
    I use "addTouchEventListener" in Xcode but it always tell me "No matching member function for call to 'addTouchEventListener'".

Comment: According to your code, `xiaoruo` should be `xiaoruoBtn`. Otherwise, you'd better provide the declaration of `xiaoruo`.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace CC_CALLBACK_1 it with CC_CALLBACK_2:

```
xiaoruo->addTouchEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onClickCallBack, this));
```

Comment: I change the code like you said,but it still wrong with "No matching......". I find the API in Xcode but I can not use it.It always told me "No matching member.......".

Comment: Just to clarify... where from do you call xiaoruo->addTouchEventListener? That call needs to be from somewhere inside of HelloWorld class.

Answer (score 0):

you can change

```
CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::onClickCallBack, this
```

to

```
this,toucheventselector(HelloWorld::onClickCallBack)
```